# AuthSchemeFactory class not found

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I am using org.oracle.httpclient package 4.1.3 and httpcore 4.1.4.

But when i execute my program i'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /sendsms.jsp at line 15

12: String mobNo = request.getParameter("mobile");
13: String message = request.getParameter("msg");
14: SendSMS httpsms = new SendSMS();
15: int sendsms = httpsms.SendSMS(mobNo,message);
16: 
17: if(sendsms==1){
18: %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:524)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/AuthSchemeFactory
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jsp.sendsms_jsp._jspService(sendsms_jsp.java:88)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/AuthSchemeFactory
    com.sms.model.dao.SendSMS.SendSMS(SendSMS.java:40)
    org.apache.jsp.sendsms_jsp._jspService(sendsms_jsp.java:67)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

i have also checked the package and the class exists in the package. please help me with what to do.

Comment: Have you placed the jars in `WEB-INF/libs`?

Comment: Of course. Otherwise, the Tomcat launcher won't add the libs to the classpath.

Comment: ok can you give me the path for the WEB-INF lib? i'm using apache tomcat server

Comment: In your java web application, you should have a `WEB-INF` folder. Create a `lib` folder under that.

Answer (score 1):

In your Java web application, there should be a `WEB-INF` folder. If that folder doesn't contain a `lib` folder, create one and add your jars to it.

Otherwise, the Tomcat application launcher won't add your jars to the classpath.